How can I automate adding group permissions to RealVNC Server Raspberry Pi Edition?
I am configuring Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm with Ansible automation. I want to be able to give users in the vnc group permission to remote into the Pi using VNC.
I go into the VNC configuration by:

Clicking the VNC Server icon on the desktop's taskbar
Clicking the menu icon in the VNC Server app
Choosing Options... from the menu
Selecting Users & Permissions

From there I can click the Add button to add the vnc group.
Obviously, adding a group this way is not easy to automate. There must be a backing file somewhere that I can edit to accomplish the same thing. Where is it and how can I edit it (preferably using Ansible.)

After some digging, I found the backing file in /root/.vnc/config.d/vncserver-x11
The line that needs changing is the last one in the file:
Permissions=:d,%admin:d,%sudo:d,%wheel:d

It needs to look like this (with %vnc:d added to the end after a comma.)
Permissions=:d,%admin:d,%sudo:d,%wheel:d,%vnc:d


The :d is to assign default permissions

Assuming VNC X11 is installed and running, the Ansible task looks like this:
- name: Discover who has permission to connect through VNC
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: grep ^Permissions= /root/.vnc/config.d/vncserver-x11
  register: vnc_permissions

- name: Give vnc group permission to connect through VNC
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /root/.vnc/config.d/vncserver-x11
    backrefs: yes
    regexp: "^(Permissions=.*)$"
    line: '\1,%vnc:d'
  when: '"%vnc:d" not in vnc_permissions.stdout'


This is a worthwhile Q&A IMHO. However, I would suggest that you delete your comments as they are no longer necessary following your edit.
